# How to cd to directory echo'd by script

Tags: macos, bash, echo, pipe, cd

I have a function `mkapp()` in my .bash_profile which creates a directory based on input and then outputs the path where the directory was created. An example: calling `mkapp createddir` would output, using `echo`, `~/projects/pub/createddir`.

I'm trying to run a command like this `mkapp createddir | cd` which would cd to the created directory specified in the output. The reason I'm not cd'ing in the function, is because I don't always want to change dir after the command.

Currently when I try to add the pipe and `cd`, I get `-bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe`

What can I do to use the pipe correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` expects a command line argument.

Use [`command substitution`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) like this:

```
cd $(mkapp createddir)
```

`pipe` is used to pass `stdout` of left hand command to the `stdin` of right hand command.

Comment: 9 seconds too quick! +1

Comment: @devnull: Thanks, you beat me all day on SO :)

Comment: Hmm.. Wondering if you're kidding or just being _too_ modest.

Comment: No not kidding at all. You and some other member's answers on `BASH/awk/sed/grep/find` etc are usually pretty fast and accurate all day.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @anubhava. I tried `cd $(mkapp newdir)` But I got the output `-bash: cd: ~/projects/pub/newdir: No such file or directory`. newdir has been created, however, when I `ls`.

Comment: Looks like your function is outputting literal `~` Try this command: `cd $(eval mkapp createddir)`

Comment: It's still saying "no such file or directory" with eval. Perhaps it's just easier if I just type cd, highlight the output and middleclick. Marking your answer correct for explaining the pipe, anyway.

Comment: You should quote the command substitution to prevent paths with spaces and globs from being interpreted by the shell.

Comment: That's a good point. @juuga: Can you try: `cd "$(mkapp createddir)"` command

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think I'll just edit my function to check if a second parameter would be `"-cd"` and then include a `cd` command in the function.